# Error: unused arguments (alist(, drop = FALSE)), R Shiny application. Have I indexed the function incorrectly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am creating a Shiny app that will allows the user to upload data, plot the data, then exclude data by clicking or brushing the plot.  It is a modification of the "plot interaction exclude" example on the Shiny app gallery.

Unfortunately, I'm running into the error "unused arguments (alist(, drop = FALSE))" when I execute the script to plot the data ("Step 2" in the code below).  I've checked my indexing and believe that it is correct. Thanks for any comments.

```
packages <- c("shiny", "ggplot2")
if (length(setdiff(packages, rownames(installed.packages()))) > 0)
{
    install.packages(setdiff(packages, rownames(installed.packages())))  
}


require(shiny)
require(ggplot2)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Rating Curve Generator"),
    
    # Sidebar 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("file",
                      "Browse to file",
                      multiple=TRUE,
                      accept=c("text/csv","text/comma-serparated-values,text/plain",".csv", ".txt"),
                      placeholder = "Browse to .csv file"
                      ),#end of fileinput
            
            #downloadButton("downloadData", "Save To File")
            
            
                    ),#end sidebarPanel
        
        # show uploaded data
        
        mainPanel( 
                tabsetPanel(id = "inTabset",
                        tabPanel(title = "Input File Contents", tableOutput("contents")),
                                tabPanel(title = "Time Series", 
                                        plotOutput("plot1",
                                                   click = "plot1_click",
                                                   brush = brushOpts(
                                                       id = "plot1_brush")
                                                       ),#end plotouput
                                        actionButton("exclude_toggle", "Toggle points"),
                                        actionButton("exclude_reset", "Reset")
                                        
                                        )#end of tabPanel
            
                            )#end of tabsetPanel
    
                )#end of main panel

        )#of sidebarLayout

    )#end of ui
########################################################
#Define server logic required to plot data with a brush#
########################################################
server <- function(input, output) {

    ##################################################
    #Step 1:  Get Data, show it to the user to verify#
    ##################################################
    
  
  vals <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$file))
      
      return()
    
    else
      reactiveValues(
        
        keeprows = rep(TRUE, nrow(datamerge()))
    
                    )#end of reactiveValues
    #print(vals()$keeprows)              
    })#end of vals
  
    #rbind all data if multiple files are selected.
    datamerge <- reactive({
        
        if(is.null(input$file))
            return()
        else 
        {
            nfiles = nrow(input$file) 
            csv = list()
            for (i in 1 : nfiles)
            {
                
                csv[[i]] = read.csv(input$file$datapath[i])
            }
            do.call(rbind, csv) # rbind the datasets
         
        }
      
     
                         })#close datamerge reactive function
    
    
    #output the merged data to contents tab and show to user
    output$contents<-renderTable({
        datamerge()
                            
      })#end output$contents (first tab)

    ###########################################################################################
    #Step 2:  Plot vals   Code fails and error unused arguments (alist(, drop = FALSE))       #
    ###########################################################################################
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        
      # Plot the kept and excluded points as two separate data sets
       
      
      keep    <- vals()[vals()$keeprows, ,drop=FALSE]
      exclude <- vals()[!vals()$keeprows, ,drop=FALSE]
      

        ggplot(keep, aes(Gage_ft, Flow_cfs)) + geom_point() +
            geom_smooth(method = lm, fullrange = TRUE, color = "black")+
            geom_point(data = exclude, shape = 21, fill = NA, color = "black", alpha = 0.25) 
                #end ggplot
    
                                })#end renderPlot
    
    # Toggle points that are clicked
    #observeEvent(input$plot1_click, {
    #  res <- nearPoints(datamerge(), input$plot1_click, allRows = TRUE)
      
     # vals()$keeprows <- xor(vals()$keeprows, res$selected_)
    #                                }) 
    
    #toggle point that are brusted when button is clicked
    #observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle, {
     # res <- brushedPoints(datamerge(), input$plot1_brush, allRows = TRUE)
      
      #vals()$keeprows <- xor(vals()$keeprows, res$selected_)
     #                                   })
    
  #  observeEvent(input$exclude_reset, {
   #   vals()$keeprows <- rep(TRUE, nrow(datamerge()))
    #                                    })
    
}# end of server 


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

sample  data (should be saved as  .csv)

```
Location    Date    Gage_ft Flow_cfs    Notes
L3R-2   1/6/2011    0.62    35.87   
L3R-2   1/19/2011   0.67    28.91   
L3R-2   1/27/2011   0.55    26.66   
L3R-2   2/3/2011    0.88    39.74   
L3R-2   2/10/2011   1.1 53.651  
L3R-2   2/16/2011   0.54    31.721  
L3R-2   2/23/2011   0.42    25.262  
L3R-2   3/3/2011    0.62    30.904  
L3R-2   3/10/2011   1.26    53.9    
L3R-2   3/17/2011   0.65    36.62   
L3R-2   3/22/2011   0.76    39.321  
L3R-2   3/29/2011   1.46    68.307  
L3R-2   4/7/2011    1.28    56.914  
L3R-2   4/14/2011   1   47.72   
L3R-2   4/19/2011   0.78    41.04   
L3R-2   4/28/2011   0.78    42.059  
L3R-2   5/5/2011    0.58    30.826  
L3R-2   5/12/2011   0.34    22.62   
L3R-2   5/13/2011   0.25    21.102
```

Comment: What do you want to do? `vals` is already a `reactive`, and then you return a `reactiveValues` object within this `reactive`, you don't need to do this, `vals` itself is already reactive. And I recommend to use `{}` for your `else` clause because it spans several lines

Comment: Thank you for the comment straka.  Unfortunately, removing the reactive statement wrapped around the reactive values causes an error that reads “…can’t be performed outside of a reactive context…”

Comment: The idea is to read in multiple csv files and bind the using the datamerge function,  then, create a reactive values object with nrows(datamerge()) Boolean “true” values.  Then, two variables, keep and exclude, are created to keep track of points that have been selected by the user. Both are plotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, rewrote the code and it works more or less:

```
    packages <- c("shiny", "ggplot2")
if (length(setdiff(packages, rownames(installed.packages()))) > 0)
{
    install.packages(setdiff(packages, rownames(installed.packages())))  
}


require(shiny)
require(ggplot2)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Rating Curve Generator"),
    
    # Sidebar 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("file",
                      "Browse to file",
                      multiple=TRUE,
                      accept=c("text/csv","text/comma-serparated-values,text/plain",".csv", ".txt"),
                      placeholder = "Browse to .csv file"
                      ),#end of fileinput
            
            #downloadButton("downloadData", "Save To File")
            
            
                    ),#end sidebarPanel
        
        # show uploaded data
        
        mainPanel( 
                tabsetPanel(id = "inTabset",
                        tabPanel(title = "Input File Contents", tableOutput("contents")),
                                tabPanel(title = "Time Series", 
                                        plotOutput("plot1",
                                                   click = "plot1_click",
                                                   brush = brushOpts(
                                                       id = "plot1_brush")
                                                       ),#end plotouput
                                        actionButton("exclude_toggle", "Toggle points"),
                                        actionButton("exclude_reset", "Reset")
                                        
                                        )#end of tabPanel
            
                            )#end of tabsetPanel
    
                )#end of main panel

        )#of sidebarLayout

    )#end of ui
########################################################
#Define server logic required to plot data with a brush#
########################################################
server <- function(input, output) {

    ##################################################
    #Step 1:  Get Data, show it to the user to verify#
    ##################################################

    
  
    #rbind all data if multiple files are selected.
    datamerge <- reactive({
        
        if(is.null(input$file))
            return()
        else 
        {
            nfiles = nrow(input$file) 
            csv = list()
            for (i in 1 : nfiles)
            {
                
                csv[[i]] = read.csv(input$file$datapath[i])
            }
            lAg<-do.call(rbind, csv) # rbind the datasets
            #Values<-rep(TRUE,nrow(lAg))
            #cbind(lAg,Values)
         
        }
        
                       })#close datamerge reactive function
      
      #mergeData<-datamerge()
      #vals<-reactiveValues()
    
    vals<-reactiveValues(
      keeprows = rep(TRUE, NROW(isolate(datamerge()))))
    
    
    

    
    #output the merged data to contents tab and show to user
    output$contents<-renderTable({
        datamerge()
       
      })#end output$contents (first tab)
    
    
    
    ################################
    #Step 2:  Plot vals            #
    ################################
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        
      # Plot the kept and excluded points as two separate data sets
     #vals$keeprows=rep(TRUE,nrow(datamerge()))
     # print(vals$keeprows)
      
      keep    <- datamerge()[ vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]
      exclude <- datamerge()[!vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]
      

        ggplot(keep, aes(Gage_ft, Flow_cfs)) + geom_point() +
            geom_smooth(method = lm, fullrange = TRUE, color = "black")+
            geom_point(data = exclude, shape = 21, fill = NA, color = "black", alpha = 0.25) 
                #end ggplot
    
                                })#end renderPlot
    
    # Toggle points that are clicked
    observeEvent(input$plot1_click, {
      res <- nearPoints(datamerge(), input$plot1_click, allRows = TRUE)
      
      vals$keeprows <- xor(isolate(vals$keeprows), res$selected_)
                                    }) 
    
    #toggle point that are brusted when button is clicked
    observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle, {
      res <- brushedPoints(datamerge(), input$plot1_brush, allRows = TRUE)
      
      vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
                                        })
    
    observeEvent(input$exclude_reset, {
      vals$keeprows <- rep(TRUE, nrow(datamerge()))
                                        })
    
}# end of server 


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```